# Why add a new column to a table in SQL Server breaks the view that's using '*'

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

We have a table X with columns A, B and C.

We create a view Y that is:

```
select * from X
```

When adding a new column `D` to `X`, the view returns wrong data.

From what I know, it happens because the view uses `'*'`, but why?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: There is a section on views in the article [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list). It is 11 years old, but still as relevant today as it was then. Long story short, don't use `SELECT *` in production code.

Comment: Add error message...

Comment: @Amirhossein is not an error. But bad data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using a database that compiles the view when it is written -- but doesn't detect schema changes.

I have definitely seen such things happen in SQL Server.  In that database, you need to add the `schemabinding` option.  The basic idea is that you need to recompile or recreate the view after any schema changes.